# Ubuntu File and folder permissions

Tags: 14.04, permissions, files, directory

`sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs`

output is

`chmod: changing permissions of ....  Operation not permitted`

I want to give every permission to htdocs and all its sub-folders and to every file on all the sub-folders  .

Thanks

Comment: Try `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /opt/lampp/htdocs`

Comment: Why would you want to that?

Comment: Not working @Helio & Elder Not everything got the permissions , I copied my project folder to htdocs where it should be . Now not all the files are loading .
I want to give every permission to htdocs . read write execute delete .

Comment: Try this: `sudo su` and then type your original command in the root prompt.

Comment: Try sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/*

Comment: @Helio hi, why do not you include you comment in answer? It has helped me.

Comment: @sangharsh: I think that this dirty hack doesn't deserve to be an answer. If it worked for you, simply upvote the comment to give it more visibility. However, if do you find my comment so interesting, make a answer by yourself with the command. Then notify me and I'll upvote. **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather recomment you to have different permissions for directories and files, because you'll need to run some commands inside of directory (like ls, cp, cat etc.), and they require "executable" permission.

At the same time I strongly recommend you to add "executable" bit only to that files, that **should be** executable - some scripts, commands, etc.

You may use the following scheme to set permissions on files&directories separately:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

for directories

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

for files,

Instead of ‘.’ you may use the full path to needed file or directory. 775 & 664 - are binary-written permissions. More information about them you may receive there - http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

If you'd like to provide full permissions on files and directories, you may perform the following:

```
sudo find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

for directories

```
sudo find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
```

for files.

Also take care about owner:group_owner parameters, they're also important for you.

Comment: Still not working Bro

Comment: Show us the output of:
`sudo ls -lsa /opt/lampp/htdocs` please

Comment: output :
total 72
 4 drwxrwxrwx  7  755 www-data  4096 مارچ  13 01:56 .
 4 drwxr-xr-x 30 root root      4096 مارچ  12 18:32 ..
 4 -rw-rw-rw-  1  755 www-data  1441 نومبر 12 20:49 applications.html
 4 -rw-rw-rw-  1  755 www-data  2142 اپريل 29  2013 bitnami.css
 4 drwxrwxrwx 20  755 www-data  4096 مارچ  12 18:25 dashboard
 4 drwxrwxrwx  2  755 www-data  4096 مارچ  12 18:24 img
 4 -rw-rw-rw-  1  755 www-data   256 فروري  6  2009 index.php
 4 drwxrwxrwx 12  755 www-data  4096 مارچ  12 18:08 shuffle_source